# Is there any practical reason to check if something is destructible before calling its destructor?

Tags: c++

So I've been messing around trying to implement a variant/tagged union class and needed a way to write generic destructors and made what I thought was a silly mistake forgetting that some types don't have destructors, doing something like

```
template<typename T> 
void destruct(T& thing) {
    thing.~T();
}
```

Yet, this worked fine even with types that didn't have destructors, like `int` or `struct A {int b;};`. I still think it's more readable and easier to reason with something that uses something like this

```
template<typename T>
void destruct(T& thing) {
    if constexpr(std::is_destructible<T>::value) {
        thing.~T();
    }
}
```

But is there actually any difference between the code? The first one feels pretty undefined behavoiry/just wrong to me.

Comment: If something is not descrutible, you generally wouldn't want to construct one in the first place. It it very strange for a type to be constructible and not destructible. Edit : It is even stranger to call a destructor explicitly. The only use case is to match a placement new. Is this for an allocator of some sort?

Comment: Why are you receiving the object by value to destruct it? If you receive it by value, it'll be destructed when the function returns with no action on your part (but it might have been constructed to call the function in the first place).

Comment: AFAIK, `thing.~T();` is always legal, even if `T` is an `int`.  Personally I would not write the if statement,

Comment: @ShadowRange just wrote down the code wrong in the question, thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver It isn't legal if the destructor is `= delete` or `private`.

Comment: If feels like that condition should be in a `static_assert` instead. It probably doesn't make sense to call `destruct` for a non-destructible type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Aha.  That would do it.  I never really deal with those use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yet, this worked fine even with types that didn't have destructors, like int or struct A {int b;};

Those are examples of types that are trivially destructible. It is well defined to invoke their "destructor". It has no effects.

> But is there actually any difference between the code?

Only for types that are not destructible. Trivially destructible types are destructible.

For non-destructible types such as `void`, function types, or types with `~T() = delete;`, the first function is ill-formed while the latter is well-formed with empty body. It depends on the use case which one is more useful, but silently ignoring attempt to destroy something that is not destructible seems dubious to me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check. In this context for a type like `int` it translates to a pseudo-destructor call. The result is a near no-op

> [[expr.pseudo]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.pseudo)
>
> 1 The use of a pseudo-destructor-name after a dot . or arrow ->
>   operator represents the destructor for the non-class type denoted by
>   type-name or decltype-specifier. The result shall only be used as the
>   operand for the function call operator (), and the result of such a
>   call has type void. The only effect is the evaluation of the
>   postfix-expression before the dot or arrow.
>
> 2 The left-hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. The
>   left-hand side of the arrow operator shall be of pointer to scalar
>   type. This scalar type is the object type. The cv-unqualified versions
>   of the object type and of the type designated by the
>   pseudo-destructor-name shall be the same type. Furthermore, the two
>   type-names in a pseudo-destructor-name of the form
>
> ```
> nested-name-specifieropttype-name :: ~ type-name
> ```
>
> shall designate the same scalar type (ignoring cv-qualification).

This sort of expression exists in the language deliberately, in order to make the writing of generic code easier. So your `destruct` is fine without the `if`.

As an aside, you might be interested to know that the standard library has a function like that. It's [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at). Other than handling arrays as a special case, it pretty much does what you do already.

Comment: What about private or deleted destructors?

Comment: @NathanOliver - What about them? (A) The OP asked about types that don't have a destructor at all. (B) The standard library itself recognizes such pathologies as not not worth the bother in practice. You won't find a standard container that works with such types.